# MongoDB select type object only

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to select documents using the `$type` operator.

Here is my collection :

```js
{id: 1, a: [{b: "", c: ""}]},
{id: 2, a: {b: "", c: ""}}
```

Here is my queries :

```js
db.collection.find( {a: { $type: "array"}} )
// It will return id: 1

db.collection.find( {a: { $type: "object"}} )
// It will return id: 2 AND id: 1
```

With the second query, I want to select only the object type.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/kp6UVzrUzjA
I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Maybe try `{$not: {$type: "array"}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each type match with the type or with array that contains at least one member of that type. [see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#arrays)

Query

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kYGnqyfEP7h)

```js
db.collection.find({
  a: {
    $not: {
      $type: "array"
    },
    $type: "object"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [ { $type: "$a" }, "object" ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[$type (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/)

> Unlike the `$type` query operator, which matches array elements based on their BSON type, the `$type` aggregation operator does not examine array elements. Instead, when passed an array as its argument, the `$type` aggregation operator returns the type of the argument, i.e. "array".